# MODx emails not working

Tags: php, email, modx

On my server, sending emails with MODx (version 2.2) fails. It would probably work with SMTP, but in principle it should work without SMTP as well, since scripts like the one below work.

Script:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Can you help me find the reason for this misbehaviour and/or solve this problem?

**Edit**

To answer the questions below:

I don't try to send any fancy emails to site users. I am just trying very basic stuff like resetting login and passwords via email.

I tried [quickemail](http://bobsguides.com/quickemail-snippet-tutorial.html) for debugging. The output is:

```
System Settings (used if property is missing):
emailsender System Setting: xxx@xxx.xx
site_name System Setting: MODX Revolution
Properties (from parameters, property set, or snippet default properties:
Tpl chunk name:
subject:
to:
fromName:
replyTo:
emailSender:
allowHtml: 1
message:
Final Values (actually used when sending email):
subject: Default Subject
to: xxx@xxx.xx
fromName: xxx@xxx.xx
replyTo: xxx@xxx.xx
emailSender: xxx@xxx.xx
allowHtml: 1
Message Body: Default Message
Send Failed
Mailer error info: Could not instantiate mail function.
Server Debug Information:
```

I think I already do use MOD-Mail with the core installation. Isn't that right?

My mailserver uses qmail. I just tried the script above without a `$from` value, and it worked. Buts still, MODx cannot send emails.

Comment: what package are you using to send email? [formit? register?] perhaps the from email address is not populated, some mail servers may not like that.

Comment: also - give modMail a spin & see if you can send mail with it: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modMail

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check that the default settings used by MODx match those of your servers [PHP mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) configuration.

The PHP mail class MODx uses is at **core/model/modx/mail/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php**. If they do not match I do not recommend changing the class, instead use SMTP which can be enabled and configured within the MODx Manager under **System > System Settings**

Info: By default MODx sends email using **/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f**. It is pretty common but wont work on all web servers.

Comment: he is not using the MODx mailing class.

Comment: It sounds like he is sending mail *through* MODx which does use the MODx mailing class...

Comment: hm i can't find any settings that don't match. Also at least the file /usr/sbin/sendmail exists. Are there any further investigations I can make?

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the `mail`-function, you are using the native (standard) PHP mail-class.

Modx revo has it's own, but you are not using the class at all. This is installed by default so it should be working. Read this wiki-article for usage of the class: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modMail

However, if sending email does not work, this has nothing to do with Modx, and as far as I can see, your code is valid. This is rather a server/PHP-setup question.

Comment: I think you have misread the problem. The script he posted *does* in fact work. The issue is that sending mail through MODx does not.